# Little Yus (Cyrillic) in LaTeX

Tags: unicode, font-encodings, cyrillic

I tried to write a "Little yus" letter (Ѧ, ѧ) in LaTeX using X2 package. But there is only Big Yus letter in it. How to use a little one? Thanks.

Comment: And what's about letter "Yn"? (Ꙟ ꙟ)

Comment: Little yus was removed from Russian in 1708. big yus remained in usage in Bulgarian until 1945. The developers of the X2 encoding chose to include all letters in current Cyrillic alphabets (a few are not covered, though); big yus found its way in a free slot, little yus didn't.

Comment: @egreg Little yus is used till nowadays.. It is more popular than a big one.

Answer (score 1):

I have done an accurate search on the internet and I have found that it is most probably a unicode font. It must of course be used with the correct encoding in LaTeX and with the appropriate package: see `fontspec`.

Reading this link https://digitalheir.github.io/mathy-unicode-characters/ or if you prefer here http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=U%2B0467, you find that the `U+00466` unicode is Cyrillic capital letter little yus and the relative command to use is, for LaTeX, `\CYRLYUS`.

Instead for Cyrillic small letter little yus the command is `\cyrlyus` that it is associated to `U+00466` unicode.  It is very important also to see, possibly, this link:
https://cromwell-intl.com/russian/latex.html
where there is an exhaustive explanation (see §2) as you can define some Cyrillic fonts.

### ADDENDUM:

For your question I have done a further search (very difficult to me for your few informations). The font `Little yus` is used from [churchslavonic](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fonts-churchslavonic) font known as Church Slavic and Old Church Slavonic. In this list, there are several `.otf` or `.ttf` fonts which can be used:

> FedorovskUnicode.otf   179 kB  2017-01-31
>   FedorovskUnicode.ttf    313 kB  2017-01-31
>   GPL.txt 36 kB   2016-10-13
>   IndictionUnicode.otf    888 kB  2017-01-31
>   IndictionUnicode.ttf    313 kB  2017-01-31
>   LICENSE 513 2016-10-13
>   MenaionUnicode.otf  366 kB  2017-01-31
>   MenaionUnicode.ttf  421 kB  2017-01-31
>   MonomakhUnicode.otf 152 kB  2017-01-31
>   MonomakhUnicode.ttf 540 kB  2017-01-31
>   OFL.txt 4 kB    2016-10-13
>   PomorskyUnicode.otf 103 kB  2017-01-31
>   PomorskyUnicode.ttf 214 kB  2017-01-31
>   PonomarUnicode.otf  193 kB  2017-01-31
>   PonomarUnicode.ttf  490 kB  2017-01-31
>   README  1 kB    2017-02-01

I've tried some of them and among them the most beautiful one seemed to me `MenaionUnicode.otf`. With this minimal working example it is possible to use 
Cyrillic small or capital letter little yus as you requested without the use of `X2` encoding.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguages{russian,churchslavonic}
\usepackage{churchslavonic}
\newfontfamily\churchslavonicfont[Script=Cyrillic,Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1]{MenaionUnicode.otf} %<---------It can be replaced with what you like from the %list.
\begin{document}
\begin{churchslavonic}
ѧ, Ѧ, ѧ
\end{churchslavonic}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you should drop all your legacy 8-bit font encodings from last century, load `fontspec`, and use a Unicode font that has this letter.  If you are writing text in Old Russian or Old Church Slavonic, it is likely that you want to load either `babel` and set `\babelfont` or `polyglossia` and set `\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont`.

If you want to load this one letter from a different font than your main font, here is a contrived MWE.  (In reality, Linux Libertine has both letters.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec, newunicodechar}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}[Scale=1.0]
\newfontfamily\symbolfont{Libertinus Serif}

\newunicodechar{^^^^0467}{{\symbolfont\symbol{"0467}}} % ѧ 

\begin{document}
 Ѧѧ
\end{document}
```

[image: Libertine sample]

If you don’t know in advance whether the currently-selected font will have a small yus, you could rewrite the command to check `\iffontchar`.

You correctly observed that there are many other ways to write that command.  For example, `\newunicodechar{ѧ}{{\symbolfont ѧ}}`.  Personally, I tend to write it as above because I use this schema for obscure characters that might not display correctly in all editors, and because many symbols have look-alikes in Unicode and I want to be very blatant about exactly what my command is doing.  But, it may only make sense to edit your document in a font where the letter is readable. Write it however you prefer.

Comment: Very good. I'm very expert how to use the number of the symbol: i.e. ^^^^0467 etc. I have used another way. What is the complete MWE thus I see how work your code, please?

Comment: @Sebastiano Posted.

Comment: Thank you very much..my +1 there was before :o)

Comment: I use PdfLaTeX..

Comment: @ЕгорКарпов Okay. By the way, if you only want PDFTeX-specific answers in the future, you can add the `pdftex` tag to your question.

Comment: @ЕгорКарпов The only packages I’m aware of require native Unicode support. With some effort, it would be possible to re-encode the [Unicode Church Slavonic fonts](https://ctan.org/pkg/fonts-churchslavonic) into four Type-1 fonts: T2A, T2B, T2C and a symbol font with unique (U) encoding for the leftovers. You could perhaps throw in T1 and TS1 while you’re at it.  Then, you could use the `\newunicodechar` technique, or `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` from `inputenc`, to insert the special character from its slot in the U-font.

Comment: @ЕгорКарпов Copy-paste would break. However, unless you’re forced to use PDFLaTeX, I’d recommend that you switch. A few sites don’t support anything else, but that’s a bad idea if they have to print papers that need Unicode support.

Comment: @ЕгорКарпов Another solution would be to create a small PDF of the Old Church Slavonic text you want to include and embed that.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to follow your advices.